# capture and compare images

Tags: c#, vb.net

is there a way to grab a screen capture of a specific section of the screen and compare it to another image already store in disk. And if the image is identical, it would prompt something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to compare an image (or part of it) with another images, I searched internet and found that leadtools has correlation functions that compare an image with all the areas of the same dimensions in another image. For more information, see this link: http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/po/leadtools.imageprocessing.core~leadtools.imageprocessing.core.correlationcommand.html

OR

This project may be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/cameronmcefee/Image-Diff-View-Modes/commit/8e95f70c9c47168305970e91021072673d7cdad8

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/ for examples on how to capture the screenshot.

The image comparison is a lot more complicated. The image that is stored on disk might have a different size, a different aspect ratio, or a different depth. Unless you can be sure that the screenshot and the image on the disk are absolutely identical, you'll have to look at a method that identifies **similar** images.

Take a look at [the pHash Demo](http://phash.org/demo/), which takes two images and outputs a similarity score. The algorithm it uses is pretty straightforward, and is available on the website.